# Can't retrieve data from mongodb using mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm really sorry about this topic. I see many others, but anything could help me to solve my problem.

So, I'm using Go + mgo in my backend and the structure that I have to search for is:

```
type Video struct {
    ID           bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Title        string        `bson:"title"`
    Duration     string        `bson:"duration"`
    Url          string        `bson:"url"`
    DefaultThumb string        `bson:"defaultthumb"`
    SiteID       SiteProfile   `bson:"siteid"`
}
```

The table "videos" has 2kk+ of information and first, I have to select these videos from his site profile that has stored in this structure:

```
type SiteProfile struct {
    ID         bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Name       string        `bson:"name"`
    Site       string        `bson:"site"`
    ExportUrl  string        `bson:"exportUrl"`
    ExportType string        `bson:"exportType"`
}
```

Then, I'm doing this command to fetch the requests that have same profile, inside a loop of profiles:

```
    var videos []Video
    collVideos.Find(bson.M{"siteid.name": profile.Name}).All(&videos)
```

In the log messages, I'm getting an empty array and doing the same thing using Robomongo, that is node based, I have these rows listed by they site profile normally. So, does anybody know how can I retrieve these data, searching for the nested object?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: please not ignore error return of `Find`.

Comment: @JiangYD thanks! I correct these line of code, but, no error has returned!

Comment: Try checking mgo logs using these mgo.SetDebug(true)
 mgo.SetLogger(log.New(os.Stdout,"err",6))

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is really weird, but when I rewrite the code, verifying the error from the find method, it works. I just did this:

```
    var videos []Video
    err := collVideos.Find(bson.M{"siteid.name": profile.Name}).All(&videos)
    CheckError(err)
```